# How to remove the same directory mounted to different mounts

Tags: mount

I tried to create few mounts for two local directories in Ubuntu 20.04 but ended up with this scenario. Clearly I made a mess. I want to delete all of these. How can I do that?

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /mnt/student_report_files type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /mnt/students type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /mnt/students type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /var/www/students/shared/files type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /mnt/student_report_files type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /var/www/students/shared/attachments type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard)
```

So if I manage to delete those above 6 wrong mounts, will it delete this one as well? I didn't create this

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard)
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: You can specify a directory e.g. `sudo umount /mnt/student_report_files`. Do this before removing them from `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, umount worked perfectly fine. Saved my day

Comment: @karel Yes, it answered my question. Thanks

Comment: Wanted to mark as answer but couldn't find any way to do that.

Comment: @Larrikin If the above link answered your question please click the "Yes" option to the right of "Does this answer your question?" in the light blue banner above your question.

Comment: Yep, did that. Thanks a lot